# Amazon S3 Bucket listing via Perl is throwing XML error

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to list all elements in bucket (Amazon S3). This worked fine till last month. Now throwing error:

Code:

```
    use Amazon::S3;
   my $s3 = Amazon::S3->new({   aws_access_key_id     => $aws_access_key_id,
         aws_secret_access_key => $aws_secret_access_key,
         retry                 => 1
     }
     );
     my $bucket = $s3->bucket("mybucket");
    $response = $bucket->list;
```

This one throws the following error:

```
Character reference &#1; refers to an illegal XML character () [Ln: 2, Col: 8456606880]
```

Is it because of the number of elements in the bucket? its more than 100k.

Any solution to suppress this?

Comment: It sounds like one of the modules is choking over something returned from S3's API, which might be an object key containing something resembling `&#1;` or ascii 0x01.  Capture the response body from the http request and examine it. It's unfortunate that you have to dig into the module code like that, when it seems reasonable to expect the code to "just work" or report a meaningful error... but the code quality of the S3 modules available on CPAN is pretty poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its not a perfect solution , i just commented out 2 lines in the below perl module and it worked fine.

```
/usr/local/share/perl5/XML/SAX/PurePerl.pm
```

Commented line (387 and 388):

```
    383     if ($data =~ /^#x([0-9a-fA-F]+);/) {
    384         my $ref = $1;
    385         $reader->move_along(length($ref) + 3);
    386         my $char = chr_ref(hex($ref));
    387         #$self->parser_error("Character reference &#$ref; refers to an illegal XML character ($char) 1", $reader)
    388         #    unless $char =~ /$SingleChar/o;
    389         $self->characters({ Data => $char });
    390         return 1;
    391     }
```

Dont know why it had to crib when it worked fine with it later.